# Unable to display Google Maps in iOS emulator

Tags: flutter, google-maps, flutter-dependencies, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using Flutter for implementing the Google Maps API in my iOS app. However, when I try to run the code in the iOS emulator (iPhone 15 Pro Max), there is no map displayed. I can however see the Google logo and the "current position" icon.

When i run "flutter run" I get this message:

`Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 7.4.0.0 New version of Google Maps SDK for iOS available: 8.2.0.0 Request failed: 100`

Seems to me, that Flutter is trying to get the new SDK but the request fails. Why is this? I have tried to update the SDK manually by typing "pod update" in the terminal, but it doesn't make any difference.

Any idea why this is?